# What is the impact in travel history after visiting Russian federation? can i apply for Schengen?

Tags: visas

i have visted Russian Federation, how it is impact to apply Schengen, is it considerable?

Comment: Depending on where you are from, it might even help *a little bit* since it builds up your travel history. if you went there and returned without overstays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doesn’t make a (negative) difference. It is Russia - the largest country in the world, not a disputed international territory.

European  issues with Russia are political and not of the nature that they start refusing people who have visited there.

Russia is one of the most well known countries in the world and last year scores of tourists from all over the world were there for the World Cup. If that could cause any immigration issues nobody would go.

Comment: You know a score is twenty, right?